# HTML/JS open a window to the C$ drive

Tags: javascript, html, windows

I need to have a link in my application that opens a remote C drive window to a certain machine.

For example, this works...

```
<a href='\\dev_pc101" />\C$'>Connect to C</a>
```

BUT... I need to do it from a piece of JS code. so I'd like to do something like this....

```
function raiseQueryDialogConfirmRemoteDrive(arg) {
  if (arg == 'button1')
  {
    window.open("\\dev_pc101\C$");
  }  
}
```

The above code though just tries to open a new window to..

```
http://localhost:8080/dev_pc101C$
```

And I just want a connection to \dev_pc101\C$

Any ideas?

Thanks
Jeff Porter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
window.open("file://\\\\dev_pc101\\C$");
```

Comment: this only works in IE but when we go for Firefox or Chrome it doesnt...!!! - Any other solutions then please post them