# Open a specific location on my computer using anchor tag or input tag

Tags: javascript, html

My requirement is to make a link or a button, on clicking it should open a specified location on my computer and I cannot use jquery but I can use javascript.

I tried doing with input tag by coding as below, but did not meet the requirements.

```
 <html>
 <head>
    ...
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Conversion Successful</title>
    <link href="xml.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1 class=heading_position>Conversion Completed Successfully</h1>
    <div class="box">
       <input readonly="readonly" type="file" value="D:/Office/xmlautomation/">
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I'm a beginner in html still figuring out how stuff works. Thanks

Comment: Basic is right, random websites shouldn't (and aren't) allowed to open things on your local filesystem. Unless this is only something you would use on your computer, a link to a local file using the `file:///D:/...` syntax wouldn't work, you would want to keep the file on your website's directory and open it like you would any other url (`href="../xmlautomation/"`).

Answer (score 1):

This used to be possible in internet explorer (6 and earlier) assuming you didn't care much about controlling how the document/location was opened.

It is no longer possible in IE or any other browser I'm aware of (Chrome/FF) for security reasons (would you want a random site you visited to be able to launch folders/apps on your desktop?).

For the record, the old syntax would've been `file://[Host]/D:/Office/xmlautomation/` where `[Host]` was usually blank so something like...

```
<a href="file:///D:/Office/xmlautomation/">Office Automation</a>
```

would've opened the directory in question.

NB: These Urls *will* still work if they're listed in a file that wasn't retrieved over the web (eg if you drag-and-drop an html file from your computer onto your browser, links like these should work). This is so that local html files which reference each other can be opened without a web server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript also. 
Just tried, it work fine for me as long as `C$` is shared.

```
<html>
<body>
   <input onclick="CallMe()" value="ABX" />
   <script>
      function CallMe() {
        // alert('test');
        window.open("file://smewara/C$");
      }
   </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

This should help you out: [HTML/JS open a window to the C$ drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111489/html-js-open-a-window-to-the-c-drive)